# Formula for deviance residuals for Poisson model with identity link function?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, poisson-regression, deviance

I understand the deviance residuals $r_D$ for a Poisson GLM with log link function are given by
$r_D = \mu_{ij} \log(\mu_{ij}/\hat{\mu}_{ij}) + (\hat{\mu}_{ij} - \mu_{ij})$

I was wondering though what the formula would be for a Poisson GLM with identity link function? Is it the same or not?

Comment: I don't think your formula is correct. (For example, note that the $i$th deviance residual is a function of the $i$th observed, $y_i$, which your fomula lacks). Where did your formula come from?

Comment: I saw this formula mentioned in an answer posted here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99065/why-are-pearsons-residuals-from-a-poisson-regression-so-large - what would be the correct formula then?

Comment: I think that answer conflates two different things. I've put what I believe is the correct formula into my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deviance of the $i$th observation - and hence the corresponding deviance residual - is determined by the distribution family; it is not affected by the link function (except in that the link function affects the estimate of $\mu_i$).

I think the $i$th deviance residual for the Poisson model is

$\text{sign}(y_i-\hat{\mu}_i)\sqrt{2\{y_i\log(y_i/\hat{\mu}_i)-(y_i-\hat{\mu}_i)\}}$

Comment: Many thanks for this - much appreciated - makes sense!

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add that the deviance residual is defined to be zero when $y_i$ and $\hat\mu_i$ are both zero.